# VB.net replace a specific word in a string

Tags: vb.net, replace

I want to create a program that could replace a specific word which I can freely set.

Sample word:

```
Dim sample As String = "TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE STAR FISH"
```

i want to replace the word STAR into BAT so the new output would be:

```
TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE BAT FISH
```

is this possible? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want to [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) all occurences of one word with another?

```
sample = sample.Replace("STAR", "BAT")
```

If you want to ignore the case (.NET is case sensitive) you can use a regex:

```
Dim regex = New Regex("STAR", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
sample = regex.Replace(sample, "BAT")
```

(remember to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions`)

Answer (score 0):

result = sampe.Replace("STAR", "BAT") is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sample as string = "TWINKLE TWINKLE LITTLE STAR FISH"
if sample.contains("STAR") then
    dim change_star as string
    change_star = sample.replace("STAR","BAT")
    messagebox.show("change_star")
    'NOTE: output change_star
Endif
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Schmelter posted. I followed, but it not working on ignorance case. If somebody face the same problem, could follow these.

**Change:**

```
Dim regex = New Regex("STAR", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
sample = regex.Replace(sample, "BAT")
```

**To:**

```
sample = Regex.Replace(sample, "STAR", "BAT", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**No need** `Dim regex = New Regex("STAR", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)`